# Is there any way to have a node with text without Animation Nodes?

Tags: materials, node-editor

So I need a node to add and change text into my material. I know that it is possible to use Animation Nodes but i am not being able to make it run on my blender. So it would be awesome if there were any alternative way.

Edit: To clarify, I have a model with a tshirt, on which I would like to add some text to it. I want to use nodes to it because i want to randomize the text that is written on the tshirt via some python code and make multiple renders with different text

Comment: Hello, what exactly do you mean with "node with text ?"

Comment: Hey, I basically would like some way to add text to a texture on a tshirt. But I need to randomize this text through some python code. The only way that I know, would be to generate different textures with python and then randomly pick these textures. But it would be nice to do it directly through a node.

Comment: If you're fine with having a string of random letters, it is theoretically possible with nodes, but if you want legible words I don't think it's really doable. Unless as you stated you import a bunch of textures with words written on it, and then randomly swap between them depending on a random factor

Comment: Is it really possible to do it using AN? I see a solution using ImageMagick. You can generate images, then plug it into a texture node. If you have Python skills, try to install Wand (for example) in blender's python, when use it.